# .on() Jquery 2.2.2 is not working ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, partial-views

I'm new to Jquery and I'm using version 2.2.2 for my project. I have a main view which loads some part from a partial view. My views as below:

main view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<=% Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.2.min.js")%>"
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a.deleteRow").on("click", function(){
        alert("Delete Row!");
    });
</script>
```

partial view:

```
<a href="#" class="deleteRow">Delete</a>
```

When I click on the Delete, it doesn't alert. How could this be?

Comment: Is your `<a>` element being loaded dynamically (after the initial page load)?

Comment: yes. there is a button for user to add row. the row is added only when user click on the add button.

Comment: Then you need to use event delegation - `$(parent).on('click', '.deleteRow', function() {` where `parent` is the closest ancestor containing the `<a>` elements that exists when the view is first generated.

Comment: not $("a").on("click", ".deleteRow", function(){}); ??

Comment: No. What you currently doing is the equivalent of `$("a.deleteRow").click(function() {`. The `on()` needs to be applied to an element that exists when the DOM is first generated. (note your could just use `$(document).on(...` but its more efficient to use the closest ancestor

Comment: so let say i have "<table><tr><td><a>Delete</a></td></tr></table>", which should be the parent?

Comment: If all the `<a>` elements will be in the table, then give the table an `id` (say) `<table id="myTable">` and then its `$('#myTable').on('click', '.deleteRow', function() {`

Comment: Thanks very much for your professional skill!! You just solved my problem!! Your answer accepted!!

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine please check your console may be some another error would be their.I have tried below code it is working fine.Please try below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a.deleteRow").on("click", function(){
        alert("Delete Row!");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#" class="deleteRow">Delete</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to read the comments :)

Comment: my <a> element is in partial view and my script is in main view.

Comment: i have posted answer as per his requirements..comments are saying totally reverse of that..@StephenMuecke

Comment: _"which loads some part from a partial view"_ should have been enough of a hint to query it :)